# Is it possible to provide userfiles within an .IPA?

Tags: ios, permissions, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an IPA that I want to distribute to users. The IPA includes some user data that should be moved to the documents directory on the first install.

My problem is that I can copy the files from the resources directory but not delete it, meaning that the data will be twice on the device.

Is there a possibility to include data into an IPA that is put into the documents folder on install? Or is there any folder I can add to an IPA that I can access with write permissions without having the device jailbroken?

I have taken a look at the documentation but could not find anything about that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.
I believe you are overthinking it. If the amount of data is small than there won't be any problem with it being twice on the device.
If the amount of data is big, you should put it on a server and download it after installation.

Comment: Thank you! The amount of data a little bigger (600MB) and no network connection is available on the iPad devices :-(

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. All data with in the application bundle is readonly and can therefor not be modified.